# Why it's printing different for this two loops

Tags: python-2.7

So i have for example `t=[1.0, 1.0, 1.6, 1.125, 1.5]`

I want to print the indices for the elements that have the minimum value `min(t)` but i want them to start from `1`
So for this example i want to print `1 2`

It's working when i do this:

```
for j in range(len(t)):
    if t[j]==min(t):
        print j+1,`
```

Output :

```
1 2
```

But it's not working with this:

```
for j in t:
    if j==min(t):
        a=t.index(j)
        print a+1,`
```

Output :

```
1 1
```

Why is that?

Comment: `t.index(j)` is going to give you the *first* index of that value.

Comment: but j it's different every time why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. They're equal values, that's why you consider them *both* the minimum value.

Comment: the first j that comes in its 1.00 on index 0,  print 0+1=1; The second j its also 1.00 but with index 1, shouldnt it print 1+1=2 ?

Comment: ...yes. But note that `t.index(j[1]) == 0`, too. It's **always the index of the first appearance** by default with `list.index`. I'd recommend using `enumerate` and setting the starting value to `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is here

```
a = t.index(j)
```

t.index(j) is going to give you the first index of that value.

You can make this:

```
m = min(t)
cont = 0
for j in t:
    if j == m:
        print cont+1,
    cont += 1
```

**Or**

```
for idx, val in enumerate(t):
    if val == m:
        print idx + 1,
```

Comment: In your list t=[1.0, 1.0, 1.6, 1.125, 1.5] the first value and the second value are equals to 1.0